# error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, archlinux

Здравствуйте.

Обновился до python3.6

Пытаюсь запустить python, а так как у меня во всех venv'ах стоит python3.5, то ругается на то, что не может найти libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Проверяю: `find /usr/lib -name '*libpython*' 2> /dev/null`

получаю:

```
/usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libpythonloaderlo.so
/usr/lib/libpython3.so
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a
/usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so
/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

Далее проверяю: `cat /var/log/pacman.log | grep 'upgraded python '`

и получаю:

```
[2016-11-08 19:39] [ALPM] upgraded python (3.5.1-2 -> 3.5.2-1)
Двоичный файл (стандартный ввод) совпадает
```

И после pacman -Syu, всё равно в логах pacmna'a нету обновления.

Что делать? Как быть?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение не самое лучшее, но работает:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0`.

Но при этом пришлось переустанавливать либы python.